# Unicode error Python3 calendar module

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, console

I'm trying to print a simple calendar from python `calendar` module:

```
import calendar

c = calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(0, 'Russian')
s = c.formatmonth(2016, 5)
print(s)
```

On linux it works well, but on Windows I got an error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4-10: character maps to <undefined>`

All I can do to avoid the error is `print(s.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii'))` (with locale text values missed), so I'm intrested in common nice solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue as following:

```
import platform

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Russian")

...
print(s) # Works!
```

Another option is encode/decode inside print:

```
print(s.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1251'))
```

Both cases works for file output too.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the windows console encoding is not Unicode. Unfortunately it is not trivial and there are several way to work around this.

What is the encoding of your console? You can find out in Python this way

```
import sys
sys.stdin.encoding
```

you can try to set Unicode this way only for the current console:

```
chcp 65001
python myScript.py
```

In your script make sure that your string is encoded into UTF-8.

Comment: No. Changing font to Lucida Console doesn't help either.

Comment: BTW, I use `print(s)`, because `str` doesn't have `decode` method.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't owe a windows machine. I can only suppose that something is wrong with the console encoding. Calendar outputs utf-8 and your console encoding should be utf-8 now.

Comment: Unfortunately there are severe and long-standing bugs in the Windows console that break code page 65001. If you really must print Unicode to the Windows console you'll have to use the Win32 WriteConsoleW API as a workaround. See [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) for a Python module that does this.

Comment: Maybe its easier to run python scripts in different console window (like IDLE, that handles this code well)?